# How To Add The Firebase Admin SDK Private Key (the .json file) in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to add the firebase admin sdk:
so, I Clicked on the "GENERATE NEWPRIVATE KEY" button
I got a .json file which was been downloaded automatically.

Then to add it I got a code-

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
```

Now,the question is, how should I add it to my code,which is in Python?

I tried copy pasting it,but it didn't work.
It still gave errors.

And, I don't get why we have to just put in that code as we don't even specify the file that was being downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

> And, I don't get why we have to just put in that code as we don't even specify the file that was being downloaded.

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
```

Let's say that:

```
'path/to/serviceAccountKey.json'
```

is path to file-you-just-downloaded.json